# Wordpress style and script url changed

Tags: php, wordpress

In my website, www.piorganic.in, the stylesheet and scripts are not loaded properly. Including images too.

Upon inspection with network tools, the path to the files were coming like

http://www.piorganic.in/wp-admin/wp-content/plugins/flickr-badges-widget/css/widget.css?ver=0.7

instead of

http://www.piorganic.in/wp-content/plugins/flickr-badges-widget/css/widget.css?ver=0.7

Someone has worked on this somefile and now i need guidance which file adds this name **wp-admin** to the url.

Hope i was clear.

Inshort, where are the urls setup with wordpress for stylesheet and scripts

Here is snapshot on icognito mode

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How Include a css and js in theme**

Step 1: goto header.php file and copy all path

step 2 : open functions.php file and enqueue all file here

```
    /**
     * Include CSS file for theme.
     */
    function mytheme_scripts() {
        wp_register_style( 'my-styles',   get_template_directory_uri().'css/mycss.css' );
  wp_register_script( 'my-Jscript',   get_template_directory_uri().'js/myjs.js' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-styles' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-Jscript' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );
```

**How Include a css and js in plugin**

**Step 1 : goto `wp-content/plugins/yourplugin/mainfile.php`.**

```
/**
 * Include CSS file for MyPlugin.
 */
function myplugin_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'flicker-widget-styles',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/widget.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flicker-widget-styles' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_scripts' );
```

**Step 2: Clear cache and refresh your tab using `ctrl+f5`.**

**Step 3: check console of browser check any error there.**

**Solution for above screenshot**

Problem : Resource load from path contains wp_admin

Step 1 : open you wp_config and check both url or base url in wp_option in db

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

step 2 : Login to admin dashboard and go to **general -> setting** check both url.

step 3 : open functions.php and check

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

If any include wp_admin then remove it.

Comment: Hope you didnt get my question. The templates were set fine and working.  Now i see this path being added Where can i figure it out.

Comment: I am not getting your template working.I have run that url all css are missing

Comment: yes becos the urls are mapped with piorganic.in/wp-admin/..... delete that wp-admin in url, you could see the files

Comment: piorganic.in run this inside incognito mode in crome

Comment: I added the snapshot. you can see all urls are having wp-admin in the path. I need to remove that wp-admin in the path

Comment: that's what I am saying

Comment: how did you add all style can you please tell me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132266/discussion-between-alaksandar-jesus-gene-and-vasim-vanzara).